# Is there a Tomcat-like classloader that can be used standalone?

Tags: java, classpath, osgi, classloader, encapsulation

I'm working with a Java sort-of-application-server (Smartfox) which can run multiple applications ("extensions") but has a very inconvenient classpath setup to go along with it, along with issues when trying to use SLF4J.

To work around that I'd like to wrap my applications in their own classloaders. Such a containing classloader should be much like Tomcat's, in that it

- Can load classes from a directory containing JARs.
- Prefers classes from its own classpath over those from the parent

Is there a library somewhere that has such a classloader I can just "drag and drop" in my project? If not, would it be hard to create it myself? Any known pitfalls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) (and other module systems) are designed to handle *exactly* this kind of problem.

It might look like overkill at first, but I think you'll quickly re-implement significant parts of the things that OSGi alread does for you.

[Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/) is the OSGi implementation used by Eclipse, for example.

Comment: It does appear to be what I want, but while tutorials about creating bundles are aplenty, I'm having trouble finding information about how to embed an OSGI framework/container (with either Equinox or Felix) in my application. Any information about that?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: you don't usually embed OSGi in your application, rather the other way around: you create your application (and plugins) as OSGi bundles.

Comment: I know, but my applications are themselves plugins/extensions in Smartfox, and I can't put Smartfox in OSGi. Anyway, I found something at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html

Comment: See http://www.smartfoxserver.com/docs/docPages/sfsPro/javaExtensions.htm for the details of the extension setup.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on how to embed OSGi in an application. For the simplest case it's just around 5 lines of code: http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

Comment: Well, because the integration wasn't as easy as hoped, I made my own solution (see other answer) but I'm accepting this answer anyway since it'll probably come in handy in the future.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: if this answer *didn't* solve your problem (althought I hope it was at least helpful), then it's perfectly valid to accept your own answer.

Comment: I know but it doesn't feel right in this situation. And I have a relatively high number of questions where I accepted my own answer so I need some balance :p

Answer (score 3):

Since I had trouble embedding an OSGi container and it was indeed a bit overkill, I rolled my own solution. But I'll learn to use OSGi one day, in a situation where I don't need to embed the framework.

If you somehow happen to want to use this code, it's under the "do whatever you want with it" license.

```
public class SmartfoxExtensionContainer extends AbstractExtension {

    private AbstractExtension extension;

    private void initRealExtension() {
        final String zone = this.getOwnerZone();
        System.out.println("[SmartfoxExtensionContainer] ========= Init extension for zone " + zone + " =========");

        try {

            // load properties
            File propFile = new File("wext/" + zone + ".properties");
            System.out.println("[SmartfoxExtensionContainer] Load config from " + propFile.getCanonicalPath());
            Properties props = new Properties();
            final FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(propFile);
            try {
                props.load(new InputStreamReader(ins, "UTF-8"));
            } finally {
                try {
                    ins.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }

            // construct classloader
            File jarDir = new File(props.getProperty("classpath", "wext/" + zone));
            System.out.println("[SmartfoxExtensionContainer] Load classes from " + jarDir.getCanonicalPath());
            if (!jarDir.isDirectory()) throw new RuntimeException("That is not an existing directory");

            final File[] fs = jarDir.listFiles();

            URL[] urls = new URL[fs.length];

            for (int f = 0; f < fs.length; f++) {
                System.out.println("[SmartfoxExtensionContainer]     " + fs[f].getName());
                urls[f] = fs[f].toURI().toURL();
            }

            SelfishClassLoader cl = new SelfishClassLoader(urls, SmartfoxExtensionContainer.class.getClassLoader());

            // get real extension class
            String mainClass = props.getProperty("mainClass", "Extension");
            System.out.println("[SmartfoxExtensionContainer] Main class: " + mainClass);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class<? extends AbstractExtension> extClass = (Class<? extends AbstractExtension>) cl.loadClass(mainClass);

            // create extension and copy settings
            extension = extClass.newInstance();
            extension.setOwner(this.getOwnerZone(), this.getOwnerRoom());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /* ======================= DELEGATES ======================= */

    @Override
    public void init() {
        initRealExtension();
        extension.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        extension.destroy();
    }

    @Override
public void handleRequest(String arg0, ActionscriptObject arg1, User arg2, int arg3) {
    extension.handleRequest(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

@Override
public void handleRequest(String arg0, String[] arg1, User arg2, int arg3) {
    extension.handleRequest(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

@Override
public void handleInternalEvent(InternalEventObject arg0) {
    extension.handleInternalEvent(arg0);
}

@Override
public Object handleInternalRequest(Object params) {
    return extension.handleInternalRequest(params);
}

@Override
public void handleRequest(String cmd, JSONObject jso, User u, int fromRoom) {
    extension.handleRequest(cmd, jso, u, fromRoom);
}

    /* ======================= CUSTOM CLASSLOADER ======================= */

    private static class SelfishClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

        SelfishClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
            super(urls, parent);
        }

        // override default behaviour: find classes in local path first, then parent
        @Override protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {

            // First, check if the class has already been loaded
            Class<?> clz = findLoadedClass(name);

            if (clz == null) {

                try {
                    clz = findClass(name);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // ClassNotFoundException thrown if class not found
                    // from current class loader
                }

                if (clz == null) {
                    // If still not found, then invoke parent.findClass in order
                    // to find the class.
                    clz = getParent().loadClass(name);
                }

            }

            if (resolve) {
                resolveClass(clz);
            }

            return clz;

        };

    }

}
```